# How to combine highcharts (heatmap) and table (mapping each table row with heatmap row)?

Tags: highcharts, html-table

I am generating heatmap but at the same time I have one table which has corresponding information for each row in heatmap so I want to keep both side by side.

Below is sample link for heatmap code.
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/

html code for table:

```
<table cellpadding=0,celspacing=12>
     <tr><td>Monday</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tuesday</td><td>Jackson</td><td>90</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wednesday</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Thursday</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Friday</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I embed html code in highcharts?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use use multiple yAxis (per each col) with enabled ticks / lineWidth params.

```
yAxis: [{
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null
    },{
          linkedTo: 0,
        tickLength:100,
        tickWidth: 2,
        opposite: true,
        title: null,
         lineWidth: 2,
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    },{
          linkedTo: 0,
        tickLength:100,
        tickWidth: 2,
        opposite: true,
        title: null,
        lineWidth: 2,
        categories: ['Smith', 'Jackson', 'Doe', 'Doe', 'Doe'],
    },{
          linkedTo: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 2,
        tickLength:100,
        tickWidth: 2,
        opposite: true,
        title: null,
         lineWidth: 2,
        categories: ['10', '20', '40', '59', '23'],
    }],
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/0qmt0mkq/

Comment: That is nice but i have one more column which has check box in each row and their id need to be passed to other page. Is it possible to add check box also?

Comment: The checkbox can be added only as HTML object and table.

Comment: you can add next axis and catch the label formatter. Inside the function, return the checkbox input. http://jsfiddle.net/vogsLwfa/

Comment: i tried to implement the same for x-axis but it does not fit colum wise.http://jsfiddle.net/vogsLwfa/6/

Comment: @SebastianBochan It's awesome! Is there a way how to make tickLength dynamic? So that it correctly extends for longer content? http://jsfiddle.net/42r3mw9s/

Comment: @KamilKulig Awesome! Thanks!