# Highcharts heatmap column width based on content size

Tags: html, css, highcharts, heatmap

Is there a way how to make Highcharts heatmap table behave like standard html table in regards of adjusting column width to its content?
Longer entries overflow outside of column as heatmap is preserving same width of all of its columns - even if other columns have extra space.

Fiddle demonstrating the case: http://jsfiddle.net/tvxgber9/

Code (identical to fiddle):

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon']
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123456789123456789], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]

});
```

Comment: In Highcharts heatmap series the width of each cell (point) is not related to the width of the data label - data label is added after point's dimensions are computed. The chart looks like a table but in fact all points have their x and y values and series has `colSize` and `rowSize` properties - they define the width, height and position of each cell (each cell is independent of others). Points are SVG's so they're not responsive by default. Implementing the functionality that you described seems to be rather difficult. Have you considered using HTML table instead?

Comment: @KamilKulig HTML table is a backup plan in case I find out it's impossible (or too expensive) to implement with heatmaps - that we have already incorporated. For html table I'd have to reimplement features provided by heatmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making heatmap to behave like HTML table (columns adjust their width to their content) is rather a difficult process - it's explained in my comment under the OP's question.

**Here're the steps to make it** (I don't guarantee that I'll work):

1. Make each column a separate series (`colsize` can be applied to a series only and we need a specific `colsize` for every column)
2. Find the longest label for every column. They need to be generated first so it has to be done in `chart.load` event. Every point has a reference to its data label (SVG element) - you can find `width` property there.
3. Use `xAxis[0].toValue` function to determine the `colsize` of each column.
4. Find new x values for every column - it depends on the values of spans of previous columns. Update all points.
5. Categories functionality is based on fixed value of tick interval and it won't work for us anymore. `xAxis.tickPositions` has to be used to place the ticks so they mach the columns. `xAxis.labels.formatter` can be used for finding the proper names for every x axis label.

Comment: Thanks kamil also for the working jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/14hppge7/ (from the other SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396410/how-to-combine-highcharts-heatmap-and-table-mapping-each-table-row-with-heatm/37415644#comment85822278_37415644)